# Float SQLParameters, decimal separator and regional settings

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand, sqlparameter

I use a SQLDataAdapter to select/update/insert data from/to a table in MS SQL Server (.NET Framework 4.0 as client framework). The UpdateCommand in the SQLDataAdapter needs 2 float parameters, which I add like this:

```
With _sqlDA_Prot_Points.UpdateCommand
.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Alm_PLUS", SqlDbType.Float, 1, "Alm_PLUS"))
.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Alm_MINUS", SqlDbType.Float, 1, "Alm_MINUS"))
end with
```

My regional settings are it-IT. When the DataAdapter tries to update my DataTable changed rows to the server, the Float parameters in the SQLServer Profiler show up with a "," instead of a "." as decimal separator, causing an exception.
I found no way to tell the DataAdapter how to convert the double to a string using the "." instead of the ",".

Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: How do you set the values of the parameters?  It sounds like you are using strings instead of floats.

Comment: Today, I don't Know why - nothing changed, only reboot, I am getting no exception at all. But SQL Server Profiler is still showing up paramters formatted like **@Alm_PLUS=2,0823981761932284**. 
If I run the same query in Management Studio I get the error _Must pass parameter number 5 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'_ This is due to the "," used by the DataAdapter to format my Double number